# Why require koa will cause error

Tags: koa

I just begin to learn `node.js`, when I require `koa` and execute `"node app.js"`

Have a error. Who can help me explain it ?
and how to fix it ?

Log:

```
/home/leon/Learn/JS/crawler/node_modules/koa/lib/response.js:47
    const { res } = this;
          ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/leon/Learn/JS/crawler/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:11:18)
        at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Code :

```
var koa = require('koa');    
var app = koa();    
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Which version of node.js do you use?

Comment: Did you installed `koa`with `npm install koa` before? Seems that node cannot find the koa package ...

Comment: Ahhh, and yes, @biphobe is right, it is important to now which version of node you are using. Best would be the latest version (> 7.6 - where you then can natively rely on async / await)